# LoadJava : oracle server jar dependencies

Tags: oracle, server, installation, dependencies, loadjava

When i use the command loadJava of my own jar (to load jar into the database oracle), i need others dependencies* which belong to the server installation of oracle (like javax.resource.jar, javax.transaction.jar, oemlt.jar...).

*ORA-29521 : referenced name javax/security/auth/Subject could not be found

Here is the jar i want to load :

```
loadjava.bat -debug -resolve -verbose -schema commun -synonym -user system/manager@%MY_SID% %MY_JAR%\SynchroExchange_Java6.jar
```

And i have to load the multiple jars of the installation of Oracle server :

```
loadjava.bat -resolve -verbose -force -schema commun -synonym -user system/manager@%MY_SID% %MY_JAR%\javax.transaction.jar
loadjava.bat -resolve -verbose -force -schema commun -synonym -user system/manager@%MY_SID% %MY_JAR%\javax.resource-3.1.2.jar
loadjava.bat -resolve -verbose -force -schema commun -synonym -user system/manager@%MY_SID% %MY_JAR%\ojpse.jar
loadjava.bat -resolve -verbose -force -schema commun -synonym -user system/manager@%MY_SID% %MY_JAR%\share.jar
loadjava.bat -resolve -verbose -force -schema commun -synonym -user system/manager@%MY_SID% %MY_JAR%\ewt3.jar
....
```

Is there a way to include automatically these kind of jars ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Maybe we have to add resolver on the loadjava command ?

Comment: I add -resolver "((* COMMUN) (* PUBLIC)) (* SYS))" but there is an error : ora-00922

Comment: With -resolver "((* COMMUN) (* PUBLIC) (* SYS))", it's better. There is an extra parenthesis in the previous comment. COMMUN is the schema where i load the jar. We have to specity SYS to access to the native jar.